# My function window.onblur, not working with external links

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem, when I open a link of my host, my function to detect the loss of focus works fine, but when I execute an external link, it does not work ... why does this happen?

var myWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com.ar');

myWindow.onblur = function(){ alert('myWindow lost focus'); }

I'm just looking to know if the open external link is observed or not!

Comment: onblur is for the opposite of an elements `focus`, not the window itself. Try the page visibility api.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener for the `visibilitychange` event of the document of the opened window.

```
myWindow.document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(event){
    if(this.hidden){
        alert('myWindow is hidden');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/r3hvet8m/

Comment: I already tried with "visibiltychange", "mousemove", and some other, but the result is the same, when opening an external link, I do not detect activity in the window/tab... the shared code, triggers the "alert" to the open the window and not when I leave it... Any suggestions? My test code is exactly as posted in the first message!

Comment: Friend, it works, but only the first time! If I swap between the window that executes "window.open" and the new window, more than once, it does not work anymore!